# U19.04 Nvidia 430 issue. bpfilter

Tags: grub2

I have a laptop with an igpu and nvidia gpu.

Yesterday I updated my nvidia driver to use the new CUDA and after reboot the laptop seemed to basically died. I couldn't log in for the longest time, kept getting a black screen, sometimes with 'started bpfilter'. Or nothing. Or it would be frozen depending on the grub.

I've spent the entire day troubleshooting. Blacklisting. Editting Grub. Yes I've uncommented '#WaylandEnable=false'. I have tried lightdm, as well as others. I've installed, upgraded, downgraded and purged different Nvidia drivers. Depending on grub, I can access tty, but not always.

Only way I can log in is by using nomodeset in grub, which not only means I don't have access to my gpu which I require for work, but also I can't use my external monitor which also aids in work.

Any and all suggestions are would be very very appreciated!

Comment: it sounds like you didn't try failsafe boot from grub. it loads no graphic driver and defaults to all nouveau settings with low res. you could be able to undo everything from that session. f all else fails you can undo the changes from a liveUSB.

Comment: I can boot into it no problem with nomodeset. Like I said I also tried lightdm. I can hear the login screen loading but there's no image. Once nomodeset is put it works fine. Full 4k and all ,just running on the intel cpu

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone else who stumbles into this problem.

I read a recent post with a near identical problem with my laptop (XPS 15) and they were told by dell that they're aware of the bug and there currently is no fix other than re-installing the os from scratch. I'm not sure what causes it, as I just spent the day backing up and re-installing, and now even with the 430 driver everything is working. I'd just recommend not updating to 430 if you have this laptop and haven't updated in a while, and don't require the update. Wait for the issue to be fixed (hopefully) in the next update.